# Is there any way to add elements of two lists or arrays with constant time complexity?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, time-complexity

I am trying to add elements of two lists in python with time complexity O(1). Is there any way I can achieve that?

I have tried using numpy for that matter but it did not work out well.

```
import numpy as np
st = 0
n = int(input())
end = n
l = np.array([0]*n)
l1 = np.array([1]*n)
l[st:end]+=l1[st:end]
```

Comment: You're asking "can I add `n` pairs of numbers together with one addition?" It can't be done. Why are you asking? Is this a homework question or do you have a practical problem for which this step is the bottleneck?

Comment: _"I have tried using numpy for that matter but it did not work out well."_? What do you mean by _"it did not work out well"_? It is not O(1), of course, but O(1) is anyway impossible. Still, this should work and it should be as fast as you can ever hope for.

Comment: @pault I'm trying to solve a practical problem from august challenge of codechef. I was just considering this possibility for my solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zvone I got time limit exceeded in a problem of codechef but still managed to score partial marks that's what I meant by "it did not work out well". Thanks for the response.

Comment: With those problems, usually the solution to the calculation which is too slow is not calculate it at all. There is probably a trick to avoid calculating everything...

Comment: @zvone Solved it completely! Turns out the problem was weak test cases! haha..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you have millions of numbers you will have to execute millions of additions.  There is no way to achieve this in constant time (*O*(1)).

Comment: Thanks for this response. I'm actually stuck at a problem. I'll try another approach.